# Captura de um determinado link em um array

Tags: php

Preciso verificar se existe e capturar links que contenham (youtube.com/embed) em um array.
A posição do link no array é sempre variável.
Como devo fazer?

```
Array
(
    [0] => esqueci
    [1] => de
    [2] => entrar
    [3] => no
    [4] => link
    [5] => https://www.youtube.com/embed/zHNOQpl00_I
    [6] => para
    [7] => poder
    [8] => testar,
    [9] => https://www.google.com.br,
    [10] => https://terra.com.br,
    [11] => https://www.youtube.com/videos/asdasd
    [12] => 

)
```

Desde já agradeço,

Comment: O item 11 entra na captura ou não?

Comment: Não... eu preciso verificar e pegar só os links que sejam do youtube com embed. =/

Answer (score 0):

use `for` para percorrer seu `array`, e use a função [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php)

```
for($i = 0; $i < $array.length; $i++){

  // valor é um item do array
  $findme   = 'youtube.com/embed';
  $pos = strpos($array[$i], $findme);

    if ($pos === false) {
     echo "A string '$findme' não foi encontrada no array '$array[$i]'";
    } else {
      echo "A string '$findme' foi encontrada na string '$array[$i]'";
      // aqui $array[$i] estara sua url.
      echo " e existe na posição $pos"; 
    }

}
```

Comment: Se eu mando buscar o link inteiro funciona, mas se for uma parte do link ex youtube.com/embed ai dá erro. =/

Comment: @DiegoAlbuquerque editei, acredito que agora seja o que estava precisando